# Build whole web application not per page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I created a website on MVC C# and locally it behaves as it is expected, but once I upload it on Azure it starts loading slow (initial load), each page takes its own time. I've enabled the Always On feature, but it didn't do much good. Now the question is if there is a way to force on access the whole web application to be build instead of the Page by page mode that is currently active.

Comment: Are you sure there's not something else running slowly in your request pipeline, or a global filter?  eg. are you accessing a database on every request?

Comment: What kind of app service plan do you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the initial request takes long and then any subsequent requests are fast, then that would be because you are hitting .NET apps cold start. Many .NET apps are slow to JIT and load all their .NET requirements, but once everything is loaded, they are fast.

As scheien said, please choose the closest region when choose app service plan.

If pages still loading slow. I would suggest you use Windows Internet Explorer Developer Tools Network Capture to find out detailed issue: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx. If it related with your application, please optimize the code.

Regards